# c# wpf determine if element has an attribute defined in the source xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to programmatically determine if a XAML element has an attribute defined.

For instance :

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Tag="tab" />
    <TextBlock />
</Grid>
```

The first TextBlock has a "tag" attribute, the second does not

I would like this method to be general such that :

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Margin="10" />
    <TextBlock />
</Grid>
```

The first TextBlock has a "margin" attribute, the second does not

Ultimately I am trying to write a function `GetChildrenByAttr(parent,attr)` which would return the child elements that have the attribute defined.

Comment: This will require to parse the actual XAML markup. You can't tell from a control instance, other than getting the value of the property of course. So how and where do you intend to use the `GetChildrenByAttr` method?

Comment: Well im still fairly new to c#, i am trying to write a generic tab method, where i can define some xaml like the first example, add a click event handler on the parent element, then test to see if the element that was clicked on has a tab attribute, and change the ui accordingly, but then add the general method to my libraries

Comment: A tab attribute? Do you mean that you want to check whether the `Tab` property has been set? Then you could just check whether the `Tag` property is `null` in your code.

Comment: aye, i tried to edit the comment but unfortunately could only edit my comments for 5 minutes, by tab attribute i mean some attribute/property taken to imply the element constitutes a tab, so checking Tag=="tab" would work for this and the general method would require parsing the xaml? I work primarily in javascript now, which has [Element.attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) is there an equivalient in c#? Ive written a naive xaml parser which will probably work for my usage, is there an actual xaml parser i could use?

Comment: There is a [XamlReader.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.parse?view=netframework-4.8) method that accepts a XAML string. But you don't need to parse the XAML yourelf just to check the value of a property of an object that has already been created by the framework's parser.

Comment: Its not checking the property value that i want to achieve, i would like to know if the xaml has a property defined

Answer (score 0):

I have some solution:

```
public IList<DependencyObject> GetChildrenByAttribute<TElement, TValue>(TElement element, DependencyProperty property, Func<TValue, bool> predicate) where TElement : DependencyObject
{
    List<DependencyObject> result = new List<DependencyObject>();
    for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i);
        if (predicate((TValue)child.GetValue(property)))
            result.Add(child);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And how to call it:

```
var result = GetChildrenByAttribute<Grid, String>(Main, TagProperty,
            value => value == "TestTag");
```

And XAML template:

```
<Grid x:Name="Main">
    <TextBlock Tag="TestTag"/>
    <TextBlock/>
</Grid>
```